# MasterPages con varios ContentPlaceHolder

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net, xhtml

Buenos dias.

Se utilizar los content place y la master page. Incluso ya serlo en forma dinámica, cambiando con varios links.

El problema es que no sé como conseguir que en la misma `MasterPage` se me carguen varias Content Pages diferentes al mismo tiempo. Tengo una `MasterPage` dividida en 3 `ContentPlaceHolders`:

`cphPrincipal` (página principal)
`cphMetodologia` (información del método de la empresa)
`cphPortafolio` (productos de la empresa)

Y deseo cargar de manera simultánea las siguientes páginas en dichos PlaceHolders:

> cphPrincipal -> Principal.aspx
>   cphMetodologia ->Metodologia.aspx
>   cphPortafolio -> Portafolio.aspx

El detalle es que cuando llamo a una de las páginas (por ejemplo principal.aspx para que se carga en el cphcontent) los demás ContentPlaceHolders se quedan en blanco y no cargan nada.

¿Hay alguna manera de decirle al ContentPlaceHolder de la MasterPage que cargue la página por defecto?

Ya intenté con este código:
MasterPage

```
<!-- contenido -->
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphPrincipal" runat="server </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphMetodologia " runat="server </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphPortafolio " runat="server </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<!-- //contenido -->
```

Ejemplo de dos aspx:

principal.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#"
 MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage/mpWeb.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
 CodeBehind="Principal.aspx.cs" Inherits="GUI.Principal" %>  
 asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>  
<asp:Content ID="Content2" 
ContentPlaceHolderID="cphPrincipal" runat="server"> </asp:Content>
```

metodologia.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#"
 MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage/mpWeb.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
 CodeBehind="Metodologia.aspx.cs" Inherits="GUI.Metodologia" %>  
< asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphMetodologia"
 runat="server">
```

portafolio.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#"
 MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage/mpWeb.Master"
 AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Portafolio.aspx.cs"
 Inherits="GUI.Portafolio" %>  
< asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphPortafolio" runat="server">
```

Pero solo carga el primero, y los demás no cargan.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es que no funciona de esa forma, la master define un template que aplicas a una sola aspx.

Recomendaria leas

[Información general sobre las páginas principales ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/wtxbf3hh(v=vs.100).aspx)

para entender el concepto.

Lo que quieres implementar solo se podria conseguir usando el iframe o [frameset](http://html.conclase.net/w3c/html401-es/present/frames.html)

[HTML frameset Tag](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_frameset_tag.htm)

en cada frame si puede asignar una pagina diferente

**>>deseo pasar la página completa con un height dinámico (la página es larga), y logré que el width sea dinámico mediante boostrap, pero no logro hacerlo con el height, ya que siempre muestra el scroll**

Para adaptar el higth vas a tener que adaptar las dimensiones usando jquery para poder cambiar el valor dinamicamente segun el contenido que se cargue

[How to change height of iframe based on dynamic conent within the iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279489/how-to-change-height-of-iframe-based-on-dynamic-conent-within-the-iframe)

[Make iframe automatically adjust height according to the contents without using scrollbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975810/make-iframe-automatically-adjust-height-according-to-the-contents-without-using)

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me funcionó el iframe, ya que desarrollo en html5, y de plano, no me sirve ni el frameset ni el HTMLTag. Pero quedó algo que no se como resolver, y es que al pasar por el iframe, deseo pasar la página completa con un height dinámico (la página es larga), y logré que el width sea dinámico mediante boostrap, pero no logro hacerlo con el height, ya que siempre muestra el scroll (incluso quitando el scroll, solo me muestra una parte), y deseo que se muestre la página completa

Comment: El link del htmltag en realidad explica el uso del frameset. Edite la respuesta para ver si esto ayuda en adaptar el heigth del iframe

Comment: Hasta ahora, eso dos los habia probado, pero lo malo es que no me funcionó. La única cosa hasta ahora que me esta funcionando es está
[https://www.teslatechnologies.es/autoredimensionar-alto-de-iframe/]
Pero funciona a medias, ya que aunque ahora me da un espacio el iframe, me lo da excesivamente largo.

Comment: No nada, ya lo logré, si dio mucho trabajo pero bueno.Ya muestra, no tan dinámicamente como deseo, pero al menos ya muestra totalmente el aspx. Gracias de todos modos.

Answer (score 0):

Cada una de las paginas (principal.aspx, portafolio.aspx, metodlogía.aspx se ejecuta de manera independiente entre ellas, pero cada una tiene acceso a la plantilla maestra y es la encargada de asignarle su contenido. Sin embargo, cada una hace uso en si de un sólo `ContentPlaceHolder`, y no asigna el de los demás.

Puedes revisar [esta solución](http://forums.asp.net/t/1243397.aspx?External+Link+loaded+in+Content+placeholder+) si deseas cargar el contenido de otras páginas, por ejemplo creando una que se llame inicio.aspx, que siga la solución del enlace llenando lo 3 elementos o poner ese código en el MasterPage.

De todas maneras, es posible que tu conceptualización no esté del todo correcta, así que te sugiero que revises bien si en realidad quieres hacer eso, lo cual no creo que sea del todo correcta.

Saludos.